# Problem with setting src for image component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, image, src

so my problem is quite weird, when i try to map in 'users' array everything seems to work fine, but the problem start when i want to do the same map to pass another prop which is profilePictureUrl prop. First rendered image have good src property but every next photo has ',' before link to photo in its 'src' property, i tried using firebase queries, and had same issue.

```
const [messages,setmessages] = useState([]);
  const [users,setusers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("messages").orderBy("createdAt").limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setmessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    })

    db.collection("users").limit(10).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setusers(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    })
    
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='MessagesContainer'>
      {messages.map(({content, createdAt, uid, isImage}) => {
          if(isImage) {
            return(
              <ImageMessage content={content} uid={uid} username={
                users.map(({uidu, username, profileULR}) => {
                  if(uid == uidu){
                    return(username);
                  }
                })}
                />
            )
          }
          else {
            return(
              <ChatMessage content={content} uid={uid} createdAt={createdAt} username={
                users.map(({uidu, username}) => {
                  if(uid == uidu){
                    return(username);
                  }
                })
              }
              />
            )
          }
      })}   
      <span ref={dummy}></span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Tried firebase queries, map, foreach and this still gives me the same result, what is wierd cuz when i console.log the URL's theyre valid so i think its the problem is in passing the value to another component

Comment: I don't see `profilePictureUrl` used in your code. Can you clarify where / how that's being used?

Comment: Actually it is 'profileULR' destructured in map function